# How to write RIGHT JOIN with union query in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new in laravel, and i have query like below that want to be queried using laravel builder, but unfortunately i am quite confused how to write it using laravel builder query or eloquent.

```
SELECT
  idMonth,
  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(idMonth, '%m')) as m,
  IFNULL(count(id), 0) as total
FROM kontrak_penjualans
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 2 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 3 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 4 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 5 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 6 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 7 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 8 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 9 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 10 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 11 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 12 as idMonth
) as Month
ON Month.idMonth = month(`tgl_kontrak`)
GROUP BY Month.idMonth
```

how to write it in eloquent or queries in laravel? especially for the `RIGHT JOIN`. :(

i have tried like this, but the code `MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(idMonth, "%m"))` return null, if i query in mysql console it perform well.

```
DB::table('kontrak_penjualans')
     ->select('idMonth',DB::raw('MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(idMonth, "%m")) as m,
      IFNULL(count(id), 0) as total'))
     ->rightJoin(
        DB::raw("(SELECT 1 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 2 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 3 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 4 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 5 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 6 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 7 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 8 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 9 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 10 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 11 as idMonth
          UNION SELECT 12 as idMonth) as Month"), 'Month.idMonth' ,'=', DB::raw('month(tgl_kontrak)')
    )
     ->groupBy('Month.idMonth')->get();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have updated my progress @JonasStaudenmeir the second select return null.. do u know why? cause i try in mysql it runs well..

Comment: Try single quotes: `\'%m\'`